# if condition inside foreach loop

Tags: c#

```
bool isexist = false;
string mytest = "A";
foreach(TestClass test in tester) {
  if (mytest == "A") {
    isexist = true;
  }
  //rest of the code 
  Methodcall(isexist);

}
public void Methodcall(bool set) {
  if (set)
    string += "This is any issue";
}
```

In above code i want check my if condition only once inside this loop & want to pass true only once in Methodcall & in next loop i want to pass false each time in methodcall because i want to print This is an issue only once.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here. What's your question?

Comment: I think you just mean to put a `break` after assigning isexist to true.

Comment: I am guessing that he wants to exit the foreach loop once the isexist = true condition is satisfied.

Comment: `isexist` may not be the variable name you should go with.

Comment: @vcsjones i dont want to break my loop i just want to check my if condition only once.so why should i use break.

Comment: The code you posted is equivalent to `bool isexist = tester.Any();` You'll need to clarify more if you want better help.

Comment: Your condition `if(mytest =="A")` will always be true.

Comment: That code make no sense. Please explain better and/or add relevant code

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - I think I just split his variable into two words at the same point as you XD

Comment: are you just after? `if(!iSexist && mytest == "A")`?

Answer (score 2):

```
bool first = true;// To do the first time
foreach (TestClass test in tester)
{
    if (first && mytest == "A")// Check if first time
    {
        first = false; // To skip the next times
        isexist = true;
    }
    //rest of the code 
    Methodcall(isexist);

}
```

But maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
bool bool1 = true;
foreach (TestClass test in tester)
{
        //rest of the code 
        Methodcall(bool1);
        bool1 = false;
}
```

?

Comment: This certainly does meet OP's requirements, but I'd strongly advise against putting code inside a loop if the code only needs to be run once.

Comment: @Doc That's the wrong idea, there are many different situations which would requite putting something inside a loop that only needs to be run once. For example, what if the loop is reading a file for integer values and outputting some calculated value to another file? If the read fails on a line you would likely want to insert an error message *on that line* rather than waiting till the file is done processing.

Comment: @NominSim If it only needs to be run once then you can just call it before you start the loop.  Anytime you see this pattern it's a red flag.

Comment: @Servy I'm assuming that the OPs naive code that has predefined "test" result is really performing the test on every element of the list without the knowledge of when it may fail.

Comment: @NominSim In your file reading example you'd stop the loop as soon as you hit the error, so you're still doing the operation *for each item in the loop that the condition is met*, you just are ensuring that never happens more than once.

Comment: @NominSim I'll agree there are exceptions, but since OP's code is evaluating a static condition that is not changed in the loop, the best practice is to exclude the one-time evaluation from the loop.

Comment: @Doc You're right, but as I pointed out in comments, the OP's original code could be simplified down to a single line. I had to assume then that the OP was reevaluating the test on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the OP's comment:

```
if(tester.contains("A"))  
{  
    isExist=true;  
}  

foreach (TestClass test in tester)  
{  
    ...
}
```

Check for inclusion, even though depending on the data type this will force a full iteration.

Comment: Can u help little bit more..

Comment: @intelliCode not sure I follow.  I am still a bit lost on your original question.

Comment: my simple question is my loop is running several times but i want to check my if condition only once inside loop...

Comment: If you mean to check a condition only once, do not put it into a loop.  For the example you've provided, you want to place the condition right before the loop, where it will be evaluated one time.

Comment: @intelliCode those are mutually exclusive ideas.  Do you want to check it within a loop or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions I can see here:

1. You mean to run the `if (mytest == "A")`  statement only once, which means you do **not** want it put into a loop.  This goes without saying, since a proper loop will do anything more than once, and since `mytest` is evaluated each time, the statement never changes.  In this case, *Woot4Moo*'s answer is likely best.
2. You meant to say `if (test == "A")` which will evaluate every `TestClass` object to search for equivalence to "A" instead of evaluating "mytest" every time.

Again, your question is a bit confusing, especially since every variable has been replaced with some form of the word 'test.'  Perhaps you could tell us more about the code's purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I gather what you are really looking for is to test some condition on every member of your list. If that test fails at least once, you want to later call a method within the for loop based on that failure, but then *not* call it again in the iteration:

```
bool testFail = true;
foreach(TestClass test in tester)
{
    bool yourTestCondition = performTest(test); // Your test here.
    if(testFail && (yourTestCondition))
    {
        testFail = false;
    }
    MethodCall(testFail && (yourTestCondition));
}
```